# Why does dividing then multiplying some large integers return strange results in Python?

Tags: python, math, division

I'm helping a friend on a homework assignment which requires a user to input an arbitrary number of seconds and display a string which represents that amount of time in terms of weeks, days, hours, minutes, and seconds.

I have a `TimeUnit` class that inherits from `int` and disallows the creation of negative units of time. I then have a `TimePeriod` class composed of `TimeUnits` that displays the string.

Specifically, it's this phenomenon that is confusing me:

```
class TimeUnit(int):
    """A class that defines the semantics of a unit of time i.e. seconds, minutes, hours etc."""

    def __new__(cls, x):
        """Ensure no negative units are created."""
        if x < 0:
            raise ValueError(f'Must be greater than zero')
        return super().__new__(cls, x)

    def __eq__(self, other):
        if isinstance(other, TimeUnit):
            return int(self.to_seconds()) == other.to_seconds()
        return super().__eq__(other)

    @classmethod
    def from_seconds(cls, seconds):
        raise NotImplementedError

    def to_seconds(self):
        raise NotImplementedError


class Seconds(TimeUnit):
    @classmethod
    def from_seconds(cls, seconds):
        return cls(seconds)

    def to_seconds(self):
        return self


class Weeks(TimeUnit):
    @classmethod
    def from_seconds(cls, seconds):
        return cls(seconds / 60 / 60 / 24 / 7)

    def to_seconds(self):
        return Seconds(self * 60 * 60 * 24 * 7)

x = 249129847219749821374782498

# Wat?
x - (Weeks.from_seconds(x).to_seconds()) # -> -2491687902
```

How is `249129847219749821374782498 -
 (Weeks.from_seconds(249129847219749821374782498).to_seconds()) == -2491687902`? It ends up causing errors when I try to represent that number of seconds in string format with my `TimePeriod` class.

```
class TimePeriod:
    def __init__(self, *units):
        self.seconds = Seconds(sum(unit.to_seconds() for unit in units))

    def __repr__(self):
        seconds = self.seconds

        weeks = Weeks.from_seconds(seconds)
        seconds -= weeks.to_seconds()

        days = Days.from_seconds(seconds)
        seconds -= days.to_seconds()

        hours = Hours.from_seconds(seconds)
        seconds -= hours.to_seconds()

        minutes = Minutes.from_seconds(seconds)
        seconds -= minutes.to_seconds()

        seconds = Seconds(seconds)

        return ' '.join(f'{unit} {unit.__class__.__name__}' for unit in (weeks, days, hours, minutes, seconds) if unit)

    def __str__(self):
        return repr(self)
```

Comment: Sounds like an epoch overflow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is the fact that you divide in `from_seconds`, this will turn the integer to a floating point value. Floats have limited precision so you *may* lose some significant digits right there. However because you subclass `int` you just store integers (not floats) and the decimal part is simply discarded (see for example what `Weeks.from_seconds(x)` returns) which will make problems even if the integer value isn't that big - and what is eventually multiplied in `to_seconds` is just the integral part of the division.

Let's go through this step-by-step:

```
>>> 249129847219749821374782498 / (60*60*24*7)
4.119210436834488e+20

>>> int(_)
411921043683448782848

>>> _ * (60*60*24*7)
249129847219749823866470400
```

To make this work correctly you could, for example, subclass or simply use `fractions.Fraction`. There this conversion works correctly:

```
>>> from fractions import Fraction
>>> Fraction(x, 60*60*24*7) * 60 * 60 * 24 * 7
Fraction(249129847219749821374782498, 1)
>>> int(_)
249129847219749821374782498
```

Answer (score 0):

Your division is ["true division"](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#binary-arithmetic-operations) that returns a `float`.  `int` is arbitrary-precision (in Python 3, which you're using), but `float` isn't, and it can't preserve that many digits (and rounds to a different `int`).